# Scons claims sources changed and rebuilds, but they did not change. Is this a bug?

Tags: build, dependencies, scons

```
scons: rebuilding `/path/to/foo' because:
           `build/xyz/libxyz.so' changed
```

I run scons repeatedly, and it always rebuilds `/path/to/foo`, and nothing else.
I am on Linux, using SCons 3.1.2.
`libxyz.so` is produced by the shared library builder, and the dependency is set with `Depends`. `build` is the variant_dir

```
from SCons.Defaults import Copy as SConsCopy
mylib = env.SharedLibrary(target=baselib_name, source=env.Glob("*.cpp"), 
                  CXXFLAGS=cxxflags, LINKFLAGS=linkflags)
my_target = env.Command('/path/to/foo', '/path/to/foo.py', SConsCopy("$TARGET", "$SOURCE"))
env.Depends(my_target, mylib)
```

So `mylib` does not get rebuilt, but `my_target` gets rebuilt every time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: SCons 3.1.2 is fairly old (From 2019). Can you try with the current released version? 4.5.2 is the current version.

Comment: how does it behave if you remove the `Depends` (just trying to eliminate sources of the behavior)?   Also... what is `SConsCopy`? SCons itself has a prebuilt `Copy` action, but not `SConsCopy`.

Comment: `SConsCopy` is the same as `Copy` (edited the question). I cannot easily try the newer SCons version for various reasons. If I remove Depends, then, of course, it stops being rebuilt due to these.